# Motivation for condition of Normed Algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Is there any particular motivation for the defining Normed Algebra with the condition $\|xy\| \leq \|x\|\|y\|$. Is there any Geometrical view of this condition?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about "geometrical view", but the condition *essentially* follows from assuming that multiplication is continuous. Note the "essentially"; we'll see below what I mean by that.

Say we have an algebra with a norm, and multiplication is (jointly) continuous. Continuity at $(0,0)$ shows that there exists $\delta>0$ so that $$||xy||\le1\quad(||x||,||y||\le\delta).$$Now given any $x\ne0$ and $y\ne0$ we have $$\left|\left|\frac{\delta x}{||x||}\right|\right|=\delta,\quad
\left|\left|\frac{\delta y}{||y||}\right|\right|=\delta, $$and it follows that $$||xy||\le c||x||\,||y||,$$where $c=\delta^{-2}$. Now $|||x|||=c||x||$ defines an equivalent norm with $$|||xy|||\le|||x|||\,|||y|||.$$

Comment: If you mention normed algebra you mean that this condition holds. I was looking why a normed algebra need this condition of norm, was it not good enough to define algebra with a norm.

Comment: Huh? If you like replace the words "normed algebra" in my answer with "algebra with a norm". I proved that if you have an algebra with a norm then there is an equivalent norm satisfying that inequality. I can't see what more you might have been looking for with your question...

Comment: You were assuming in the algebra that the multiplication is continuous and which turns out to be the equivalent for the norm condition. In that case i would like to ask why do you need the multiplication continuous?

Comment: @Arindam I don't get this. We don't _need_ multiplication to be continuous. We don't need normed algebras. We don't need mathematics. You asked for _motivation_ for that inequality. Any answer to "what's the motivation for A?" is going to be of the form "A is useful for B". Regardless of the value of B you can then ask what the motivation for B is. Then you can ask what the motivation for C is. Then D. I stop here - if you honestly have no idea why continuity can be useful you might find a calculus book.